# This code shouldn't make things harder!

Tags: cipher

What is the message?

> Doodle on grouch's jersey.
>
> To Capulet's jersey in the mountains: dance.
>
> Mountains grouch for beans, the winner again varies.
>
> Subcontinent dances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are all

> references to NATO phonetic alphabet letters.

Doodle on grouch's jersey.

> Yankee Oscar Uniform

To Capulet's jersey in the mountains: dance.

> Juliet Uniform Sierra Tango

Mountains grouch for beans, the winner again varies.

> Sierra Oscar Lima Victor Echo Delta

Subcontinent dances.

> India Tango

So the message is:

> YOU JUST SOLVED IT

Comment: That was quick!